# What attributes does the Square object have when super() is used in __init()__ function of Square subclass?

Tags: python, inheritance

Please consider the following code:

```
class Rectangle(object):
    def __init__(self, height, length):
        self.height = height
        self.length = length
    
    def area(self):
        return self.height * self.length
    
    def perimeter(self):
        return 2 * (self.height + self.length)

class Square(Rectangle):
    def __init__(self, length):
        super(Square, self).__init__(length, length)

s = Square(5)
s.area(), s.perimeter()
```

What attributes does `Square` object contain - is it just `length` attribute or both `height` and `length` attribute? If we see the arguments of `__init__()` method of `Square` class, it must contain only `length` attribute. But `super()` method is initialising both `length` and `height` attributes. How should one visualise a `Square` object?

Comment: It gains both. An easy way to test is to put some `print` statements in different functions and see which functions actually run. Or simply try and call `s.height`.

Comment: Also, you only need to write `super().__init__(length, length)`.

Comment: You can easily do `print(dir(s))` to see what attributes does it have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The square object will have both height and length.

The constructor for Square only takes in length, but that doesn't mean that the only attributes a square can have is length. When we call the super class's constructor it has 2 inputs for height and length which only length is passed for both. In the parents constructor height and length are set to length which causes Square to have both attributes.

Answer (score 1):

```
print(s.__dict__)
```

gives `{'height': 5, 'length': 5}`

So, it has both the attributes.

Additional info:- You can also use `help` on the instance for clarity. For E.g

```
print(help(s))  That will give:

Help on Square in module __main__ object:

    class Square(Rectangle)
     |  Square(length)
     |  
     |  Method resolution order:
     |      Square
     |      Rectangle
     |      builtins.object
     |  
     |  Methods defined here:
     |  
     |  __init__(self, length)
     |      Initialize self.  See help(type(self)) for accurate signature.
     |  
     |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |  Methods inherited from Rectangle:
     |  
     |  area(self)
     |  
     |  perimeter(self)
     |  
     |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |  Data descriptors inherited from Rectangle:
     |  
     |  __dict__
     |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
     |  
     |  __weakref__
     |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
```